# PWA not being refreshed on new production version in mobile devices

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, updates, progressive-web-apps, ionic3

I'm developing a desktop and mobile PWA using Ionic 3/Angular 4. I publish it in a https server from Amazon. The app is open via desktop browser, mobile browser or via home screen icon in mobile devices.

When I publish a new version and open the address in the desktop browser I get the most recent version of my app. When I publish a new version and open it via mobile browser or home screen icon I get the old version of my app.

I thought that that the PWA should manage its version by itself.

How could I force the update of my app on mobile devices?

Comment: Are you using the service worker?

Comment: Yes, I think. As far I know to enable service worker in a Ionic 3 app I just need to uncoment the service worker script in the index.html.

Comment: Service workers don't do anything by themselves, all of it's behavior is based on what your SW is configured to do. Without seeing any code we can't help much.

Comment: I'm just using the default SW code provided by Ionic 3.

Comment: You most probably need SwUpdate service for this. Take a look on the official doc https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#checking-for-updates